# divide et impera problem

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, divide-and-conquer

Given a set M, find if there is a pair of numbers (a,b), both belong to M, and a+b=x, where x is a previously specified parameter. The problem should be solved using Divide et Impera in O(n * log n). Probably the problem should be split in two half-sized subproblems and then recombine the results in O(n).

I would like a pseudocode for the given problem or a tip for solving it.

Comment: May there be negative values in `M`?

Comment: I'm happy with a solution for either version of the problem.

Comment: @Radu what you want by posting this problem.

Comment: I would like a pseudocode for the given problem or a tip for solving it.

Comment: you can achieve O(n) using hash

Comment: Using hash, in the worst case(using a poor hash function) you can achieve n^2 time complexity.

Comment: @Radu: M is a set -> no repeats. a hash function will have to 'try' hard in order to 'achieve' O(n^2)

Comment: @Amit: That is correct, exactly n^2 is tough to get, but saying that an algorithm runs in O(n) you're actually saying that under no circumstances that piece of code is going to perform worse, which is not true in our case.

Comment: @Amit: This is a homework question about worst-case complexity, it doesn't matter that the hash function has to 'try-hard', it matters that it is worst case O(n^2) when the question requires worst case O(n lg n). Also the question explicitly asks for a divide and conquer approach.

Comment: @veredesmarald: this is why this 'answer' is as a comment and not as an answer. it does not answer the question, but I think it worths mentioning in this context.

Comment: If the hash function is defined like so f:M->HashDomain, you can easily create an input set M with card(M)>card(HashDomain) and this will render the hash function not injective => collisions will appear => not O(n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this fits your requirements, but:

1. Mergesort the set (this uses divide and conquer).
2. Start with the first and last elements of the set, and compare their sum to x. If the sum is equal, you are done. If the sum is larger, step down to the second last element, if the sum is smaller, step up to the second element.
3. Repeat step two, working in from the ends to the center of the sorted set, until the elements summing to x are found, or there are no more elements.

The divide and conquer sort is O(n lg n), the stepping through the sorted set is O(n), therefore total complexity O(n lg n).

Ed: sum to x, not M.

Answer (score 2):

If you sort M (in O(n log n), using D&I), you can check in linear time if there's a pair with the right sum. (Hint: two pointers).

If you don't think that will count as a D&I solution, you can fold the checking step into the combine step of the sort and exit early if you find a match.

Addition: If you do the checking during the combine, you end up doing O(n log n) add-and-compare steps instead of O(n) -- but of course that doesn't worsen the asymptotic runtime except for the constant factor.